# extending class with private constructor in php different from version 5.1 to 5.4

Tags: php, class, oop, inheritance, extend

I have a class with a private constructor, to prevent direct instantiation.

```
class MyClass {

    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {

    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (isset(self::$instance)) {
            return self::$instance;
        } else {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }

}
```

I extend it

```
class ExtendedClass Extends MyClass {
    //cannot touch parent::$instance, since it's private, so must overwrite
    private static $instance;
    //calling parent::getInstance() would instantiate the parent, 
    //not the extension, so must overwrite that too
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (isset(self::$instance)) {
            return self::$instance;
        } else {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }
}
```

When I call

```
$myInstance=ExtendedClass::getInstance();
```

In PHP 5.4.5 I get

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to private MyClass::__construct() from context
>   'ExtendedClass'

But In PHP 5.1.6, everything works as expected

What is happening here?

**Also: I did not write MyClass, I don't have the ability to make the constructor protected, If I did that would solve the problem, but I can't.**

Comment: Why don't you make your parent constructor protected rather than private?

Comment: I can't! I didn't actually write MyClass, I don't have the ability to modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [the bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44141). You could fix your code like this (PHP > PHP5.3):

```
class MyClass {

    private static $instance;

    private function __construct() {

    }

    static function getInstance() {
        if (isset(self::$instance)) {
            return self::$instance;
        } else {
            self::$instance = new static();
            return self::$instance;
        }
    }

}


class ExtendedClass Extends MyClass {
}
```

Comment: Way to find documentation of the bug! Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: Static analyzers will complain about this code with `Unsafe usage of new static()` (IMHO, rightfully so, because `new static()` can lead to hard to spot bugs). To fix this, you should also mark the private constructor with `final`, so that it cannot be overridden.